# Which class level applies to creating a Kensai's signature weapon?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, weapons, class

I noticed the Kensai's signature weapon's maximum modifier is determined by his class level, but does that mean his Kensai level, or the class he took before he became a Kensai?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The term "class level" in the description of any class feature always refers to your level in that class.

So for that feature, it refers to your Kensai level.

Comment: Ah. In that case, is it possible to further upgrade your signature weapon without losing it?

Comment: @Cobalt: OK, third comment to answer this: yes, he can. If his signature weapon is already magic (i.e. he's already imbued it in the past), he can imbue it again to add more magic to it, paying the difference in XP costs between its new equivalent enhancement value and its old one.

Answer (score 5):

His Kensai level. If it meant any other level it would say "character level" or "fighter class levels".